# Are Korean names ever written camelcase in English, e.g., HaYoon

Tags: korean-to-english, names, romanisation

I just came across [McCune–Reischauer romanization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/McCune%E2%80%93Reischauer), but would prefer to use Korean names in camelcase, where the hyphen is deleted and the second name is capitalized, e.g., JiYoo.

Is there historical precedent for using this? Have you ever seen it published in a newspaper?

Comment: There is the [official rule for romanization](https://www.korean.go.kr/front_eng/roman/roman_01.do); however, some use a space instead of the hyphen (I really hate this way), and some others (including me) use the camelCase. I have never seen the latter way used in newspapers, but that is just my own experience.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/BoA

Comment: I think BoA is sufficient evidence. Do you want to post it as an answer, @topomorto?

Comment: I'd say BoA is a VERY exceptional case. (The pop artist Kesha used to stylize herself as Ke$ha but that doesn't mean $ in names are usually permitted.)

Comment: Absolutely a fair point, @Taegyung. 

However, between Topomorto's official answer and Klmo also mentioning a preference for camelCase, we have created a grassroots movement. All we have to do now is get The National Institute of Korean Language to add camelCase to the official ruleset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't seen this suggested in any particular style guide.

A one-off example I can think of is singer [권보아, written in Latin script as BoA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BoA).

I do write names like this myself sometimes, and agree that it is a good way of writing Korean names, insofar as it preserves the distinction between the Korean syllables while reducing the risk of the second syllable getting separated from the first and being thought of as a separate 'middle name'. If your reader is a software developer, they're also likely to be at home with camelCase, although if they're not then it might look a bit odd!