# Korean Name westernisation and addressing someone

Tags: names

I understand that typically Korean Names are in the format **LastName FirstName**, and the first name often has two characters (words).

I have a LinkedIn connection that I want to email, and they have westernised their name on LinkedIn.

However, their name is formatted **"Name1Name2 Name3"** which makes me think they may have reversed the Korean order for a western audience?

*(I don't want to post the name full name publicly, but it's "Name1Name2 An" if that helps).*

What is the right way to start my email, if I'm sending in English?

My guess is

> Hi Name1Name2

Comment: It is most likely that An is their family name. Many Koreans reverse the order of their name when they westernize it, but not always; also one-character given names and two-character family names do exist. So, "Hi Name1Name2" would work in most cases (99% of the time), but if you want to be 100% safe you can use their full name.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are Korean names ever written camelcase in English, e.g., HaYoon](https://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/5387/are-korean-names-ever-written-camelcase-in-english-e-g-hayoon)

Comment: @Absol I think this is really helpful. If you add it as an answer I'll mark accept it

Answer (score 0):

You can use anything.
Because Korean ppl are used to both.
If he/she can speak English or lived abroad, it would be more familiar.
If you're not sure, just write it
like this

```
Name1Name2 An
```